# Force vectors when a body is held by a force above the ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

[image]
In order to lift this bucket I need to apply external force(in this case muscular force)greater than the weight of this bucket so that Fnet is in the vertically upward direction and the bucket moves up.Now I reduce the force and make it equal to the weight of the bucket and according to newton's laws it should move with constant velocity.So then why does the bucket remain stationary when forces cancel out and not move with constant velocity when we lift it?
What is the physics here?Your answer will be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

The system under consideration is the bucket and take up as positive, with unit vector $\hat u$.

The bucket has two forces acting on it, the attractive force of due to the Earth, $F_{\rm Earth}(-\hat u)$, and the upward force due to you, $F_{\rm you}(+\hat u)$.

The buckets starts at rest with $F_{\rm you}-F_{\rm Earth}= 0$.

You apply a sightly larger constant force on the bucket, $F^+_{\rm you}$, total  over a displacement $x\hat u$ so that its upward velocity increases.
The net work done on the bucket is $(F^+_{\rm you} - F_{\rm Earth})\,x$.

The force you apply on the bucket is reduced to $F_{\rm you}$ and so the bucket moves up with constant velocity over a displacement, $(h-2x)\hat u$ and so the work done in this phase is zero

You now reduced the force you apply by the same amount that you increased it in the first phase of the motion, $F^-_{\rm you}$, over the same displacement as before $x\hat u$ so now the velocity of the bucket drops to zero.
The net work done on the bucket is $(F^-_{\rm you} - F_{\rm Earth})\,x$.

So the total work done on the bucket is

$(F^+_{\rm you} - F_{\rm Earth})\,x + (F_{\rm you}-F_{\rm Earth})(h-2x) + (F^-_{\rm you} - F_{\rm Earth})\,x=0$.

Note that the work you have done is $F_{\rm Earth}\,h$ and that is equal to the negative amount of work done by the gravitational force with both of these quantities being equal to the gravitational potential energy gained by the bucket (and Earth) system.

Comment: Usual question. Why the -1?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that muscular force is not precise enough to an experiment like that. We simply change the force unconsciously to lift quickly, slowly, or to stop the mass in a given position.

A better example of constant lifting force is buoyancy, when the weight of an helium baloon (summing gas + membrane) equals its weight. It is very difficult to balance it exactly, but if it is done, any slight movement up or down of our hands when puting it at a given height results in a constant velocity, instead of staying at the same location.